# Kendo js takes too much time while downloading on client side

Tags: css, angularjs, user-interface, kendo-ui, scheduler

I am using kendo ui scheduler in my project but while downloading the kendo js and css on client side takes too much time due to which some slowness is seen our website. To overcome this issue, we are trying to download the kendo js and css as per request means on only that page where scheduler calender is loaded. While integration the same we are unable to add the dependency "kendo.directive". Please suggest how to add that dependency or an alternative way to reduce that much delay.

Please find the code for the same.

```
myApp.requires.push('kendo.directives');

myApp.controller('CalenderController',['$scope', '$http', 'StatsService', function ($scope, $http, StatsService) {
    var self=this;

    $scope.schedulerOptions = {
        date: new Date(),
        startTime: new Date(),
        showWorkHours: true,
        height: 600,
        views: [
            "day",
            {type: "week", selected: true},

        ],
        editable: {
            destroy: false,
            create: false,
            template: $("#editor").html()
        },
        timezone: "GMT",
        dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    url = '/consultants/applications/interviews';
                    $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        options.success(data.result);
                    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        options.error(data);
                    });
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "interviewId",
                    fields: {
                        taskId: {from: "id", type: "number", editable: false},
                        candidateName: {from: "candidateName" , editable: false},
                        title: {from: "title", defaultValue: "No title" , editable: false},
                        companyName: {from: "companyName" , editable: false},
                        start: {type: "date", from: "interviewTiming", editable: false},
                        end: {type: "date", from: "interviewEndTiming" , editable: false},
                        candidateEmail: {from: "candidateEmail" , editable: false},
                        candidateMobile: {from: "candidateMobile" , editable: false}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom combined script, which is smaller than `kendo.all.min.js`...

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need#build-scripts

... or use individual script files:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need#individual-widget-scripts

In both cases, the size of the loaded script file(s) will be reduced.

The same option does not exist for CSS code, unfortunately.